# Usage of Forward and Backward slash as seperators for File path on Windows 32 and 64 bit machines

Tags: windows

I am using a 32 bit window machine with a 32 bit JVM. I am trying to load a DLL file on the machine and the path specified contains '\' as path separator. However if I try to '/' as path separator in Java program it is not able to load the dll with the error message as 'File could not be found'.

However when I try to load the same DLL on a 64 bit windows machine with a 32 bit JVM, my Java program accepts '/' as a path separator. With '\'  as path seperator in Java program it is not able to load the dll with the error message as 'File could not be found'.

Any pointers.

Comment: It's your program, right? Code it to accept whatever you want it to accept.

Comment: This probably has to do with the API you're using. You should post your code, and ask on [so] since this is a programming question.